# how to make sure second fork does not continue after failure, pipe and dup2

Tags: c, fork

How do I make sure I do not fork another process and discontinue my pipe if exec fails in the first child process? Do I have to do something with wait?

```
id_t pid, pid2;
int fd[2];

pipe(fd);
pid = fork();

if(pid==0){
    dup2(fd[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    execlp("grep", "grep", "alpha",NULL);
}else{ 
    pid2=fork();

    if(pid2==0){
        dup2(fd[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "alpha",NULL);
    } else {
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);
        wait(NULL);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: You really can't.  One of the major features of the pipe is that the two processes are running concurrently.  If you want to wait to see if the execlp fails, that would require waiting until the first child runs to completion.  But if that child is going to generate more than one pipe buffer full of data, it will end up blocking on a write and everything will stall.

Answer (score 0):

You need a waitpid() statement and also you need a loop (warning:this is not actual running code )

```
   int pid_status, i;

   for( i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ){

     pid_t  pid = fork();

     if (pid == -1 ) retunr 1;

     if( pid == 0 ){
          --- do you stuff ---
     }

     if(waitpid(pid, &pid_status, 0 ) == -1{
         return 1;
     }
 }
```

waitpid() will wait until the completion of the current child process.

Comment: why would I need a loop?

Comment: My understanding is this: fork a child process.  wait until this process completes.  If it completes, fork another child process.  So I thought you need 2 child processes.

Comment: how would I make sure the second process does not run if exec fails in the first?

Comment: waitpid() waits for the first process to finish.  If it fails, it will return immediately without going to the second loop.

Comment: if it is successful, then what should I do to make sure the second child is reaped?

Comment: it goes to second loop and spawns another child.

Comment: if i weren't to use a loop how would I reap the second child?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143137/discussion-between-nguai-al-and-user7252850).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make sure I do not fork another process and discontinue my
>   pipe if exec fails in the first child process? Do I have to do something with wait?

I think you have to take more care about what happens in case of `exec` failure, in particular your code does nothing special at all and the control will jump after the `if` which I doubt it is safe. Generally, one calls `exit` just after:

```
exec(...);             // if it works, ok...
exit(MY_FAILURE_CODE); // in case `exec` fails stops the program gracefully
```

Now for your original question: no, `wait` is certainly not appropriate for your needs because it will wait until the end of the process and you will be unable to launch others at the right time. But your needs may not be real needs, why do you want to take so much care about `exec` failure? After all the problem would be the same if in a chain of pipes, something's wrong appears in the middle... By calling `exit` you ensure that there will be no writer on the pipe, so that the reader will be able to detect EOF on the pipe and then stops, etc in cascading. Everything will be ok.